# How to display pdf or print pdf

Tags: php, pdf, phpmyadmin, xampp

How to **display pdf and print using php or html**? I want to **use data from phpmyadmin to make a data in a pdf**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say use dompdf which it get html file and print it in pdf you can choose wither the user view it or download it and you can put the php variables within the the html file.
github link
https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

example from the documentation

```
// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();
```